# check the data that server sends to frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "user": {
        "company": "DealerSocket",
        "email": "myphuong8892@gmail.com",
        "first_name": "Phuong",
        "id": 13,
        "last_name": "Tran",
        "profile_picture": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546074340-daca667ee128"
    }
}
```

the server give me this JSON, I want to check the email of user by `data.user.email`.However, it said:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined.

I dont understand why it throws an error. Thanks

[image]

Comment: .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=>{
        resolve(responseJson)
    })  can parse it in Json the response you are getting  and then try data.user.email

Comment: I tried to attached the picture but it  doesnt let me. they only show the link

Comment: @PhuongTran can you put the result `console.log` ths const `json`

Comment: @PhuongTran Please don't add code as pictures. We can not edit or run that code while it's an image.

Comment: you probably have to parse the response-string in first place -> `real_object = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: Check if `data.user` exists before using its fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using fields of `user` object in a `data` array, you should first check if `user` exists. When the component is rendering, data fetching may have not been finished therefore there is no `user` element inside data and get an error. The following way will solve the problem.

```
console.log("Email is: "+data.user && data.user.email)
```

When using above code, it will only print email to the console, if the `user` object is available inside `data`.

Comment: Thanks, I just think the same, when it first load data doesnt have any object in there

Comment: It works as like you said. I use this  console.log("check_email",data.user &&  data.user.email). I wont work with "+". Thank you